# How to Send Email and download the document after user has signed document using DocuSign

Tags: c#, .net, docusignapi

I am able to get the user to sign document within application itself.
But the code is sending Email also while showing the document in application iframe.

I don't want to send email to user if document is shown in the same window.
Also once the document has been signed is there any option to either download Or send the signed document to user as an attachment.

I have following code which will send email to user and show docusign interface in same window for user to sign the document:

```
  public void ShowDocumentInConsole(string name, string email)
  {
        var docuSignClient = new DocuSignClient(this.DocuSignCredentials);
        var accountId = docuSignClient.AccountId;

        //===========================================================
        // Step 2: Create and Send an Envelope with Embedded Recipient
        //===========================================================

        // Read a file from disk to use as a document.
        byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"D:\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\DocuSignTemplateNew.pdf");

        EnvelopeDefinition envDef = new EnvelopeDefinition();
        envDef.EmailSubject = "[DocuSign C# SDK] - Please sign this doc";

        // Add a document to the envelope
        Document doc = new Document();
        doc.DocumentBase64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);
        doc.Name = "TestFile.pdf";
        doc.DocumentId = "1";

        envDef.Documents = new List<Document>();
        envDef.Documents.Add(doc);

        // Add a recipient to sign the documeent
        Signer signer = new Signer();
        signer.Email = email;
        signer.Name = name;
        signer.RecipientId = "1";
        signer.ClientUserId = "1234"; // must set |clientUserId| to embed the recipient!

        // Create a |SignHere| tab somewhere on the document for the recipient to sign
        signer.Tabs = new Tabs();
        signer.Tabs.SignHereTabs = new List<SignHere>();
        SignHere signHere = new SignHere();
        signHere.AnchorString = "Signature";
        signHere.AnchorXOffset = "1";
        signHere.AnchorYOffset = "0";
        signHere.AnchorIgnoreIfNotPresent = "false";
        signHere.AnchorUnits = "inches";
        signHere.DocumentId = "1";
        signHere.PageNumber = "1";
        signHere.RecipientId = "1";
        //signHere.XPosition = "100";
        //signHere.YPosition = "100";
        signer.Tabs.SignHereTabs.Add(signHere);

        envDef.Recipients = new Recipients();
        envDef.Recipients.Signers = new List<Signer>();
        envDef.Recipients.Signers.Add(signer);

        // set envelope status to "sent" to immediately send the signature request
        envDef.Status = "sent";

        // |EnvelopesApi| contains methods related to creating and sending Envelopes (aka signature requests)
        EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();
        EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, envDef);

        //===========================================================
        // Step 3: Create Embedded Signing View (URL)
        //===========================================================

        RecipientViewRequest viewOptions = new RecipientViewRequest()
        {
            ReturnUrl = "http://localhost:50305/",
            ClientUserId = "1234",  // must match clientUserId set in step #2!
            AuthenticationMethod = "email",
            UserName = envDef.Recipients.Signers[0].Name,
            Email = envDef.Recipients.Signers[0].Email
        };

        // create the recipient view (aka signing URL)
        ViewUrl recipientView = envelopesApi.CreateRecipientView(accountId, envelopeSummary.EnvelopeId, viewOptions);

        // print the JSON response
        var view = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(recipientView);

        // Start the embedded signing session
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(recipientView.Url);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Q: I don't want to send email to user if document is shown in the same window

You can control the emails sent to embedded recipients in your account settings.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36347074/1219543)

---

#### Q: Once the document has been signed is there any option to either download Or send the signed document to user as an attachment.

Yes you can manually download the document using the [getEnvelopeDocument](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/get/) api.  See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42403346/1219543) for the c# code.

Also DocuSign can automatically attach the documents in the email. It can be configured in your [account settings](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-admin-guide-signing-settings).

See **Document Delivery** section

> - **Attach documents to completion email**. When selected all the completed documents are included in the completed email sent to senders and signers as PDF file attachments. To include the Certificate of Completion along with the documents, you must also select the setting Attach Certificate of Completion to completed documents.
> - **Attach certificate of completion to completed documents** When selected, when an envelope is downloaded as a Combined PDF, the Certificate of Completion is included at the end of the file. (The Certificate is always included with the Separate PDF download option.) If the setting Attach documents to completion email is also selected, the Certificate is included as a separate attachment to the completed email that is sent to senders and signers.